# "Refers to the missing type Point3d" in J3D API (Java)

Tags: java, 3d

Apparently the J3D API is *NOT* included in my version of JDK. I have downloaded the source code for it from [Java 3D Downloads: Release Builds — Java.net](http://java3d.java.net/binary-builds.html)

I copied both the "vectormath" and "j3d" folders into my "org" folder and changed all the `package javax.media.j3d` to `package org.j3d`...

My version (Helios) of Eclipse IDE is giving me the error:

> The method transform(Point3d, Point4d) from the type Transform3D refers to the missing type Point3d

at `transform(direction, xformDirection);`!

The *same problem* is popping up at **A LOT** of different places, except with different methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Point3d` should refer to `javax.vecmath.Point3d`.  That particular class can be found in `vecmath-1.3.1.jar`.  Do you have that jar included in your project?  One possible place to get that if you need it is http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven/java3d/jars/vecmath-1.3.1.jar.

**EDIT**

Ok, I went and did a little playing around and here.  Try these steps:

1. Visit the site you recommended
2. Choose the correct *installer* for your system architecture
3. Run the installer
4. Open your Eclipse project
5. Add external jars under the *Java Build Path* properties.  Go to the directory where Java3D was installed.  Choose all 3 jar files.
6. Your code should be fine now.  Here is a code sample (which does nothing but proves I get no errors anyway) which works for me.  `Point3d` is correctly recognized.

   ```
   package main;

   import javax.media.j3d.Transform3D;
   import javax.vecmath.Point3d;

   public class Sneeze {        
       public void test() {
           Point3d p3 = new Point3d(7, 4, 2);
           Transform3D t = new Transform3D();
           t.transform(p3);
       }
   }
   ```

The only problem I see is if you do not have privileges to install Java3D or otherwise choose not to install it.  But if you do not want to install, try the binary download and follow a similar procedure.  Hope we got it this time :)

Comment: Yes, I have downloaded it and included it in my "org" folder. I have also changed the `package javax.vecmath` declarations to `package org.vecmath` so there aren't any errors there.

Comment: Thanks for replying anyway :)

Comment: Mind posting a code example? Has to be something we are overlooking

Comment: Well, here is one program with the errors. Sorry, it is a bit long:`
                    body.getLeftEarPosition(earPosition);
                    body.getRightEarPosition(earPosition);
                    headToVwrld.transform(xformRightEar);
                    headToVwrld.transform(xformLeftEar);
                    xformHeadZAxis.set(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
                    headToVwrld.transform(xformHeadZAxis);`
This is just part of the code. I can't post the whole code :(

Comment: Errors in `body.getLeftEarPosition(earPosition);` and `body.getRightEarPosition(earPosition);`and `headToVwrld.transform(xformRightEar);`

Comment: +1 for taking the time to sort it out properly; +2 if I could, as what you've done is far more painstaking than the things I normally do for reputation round here…